# How to run an SSIS package in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Every month I get an updated list of USPS ZIP codes, which I dutifully import into my SQL Server 2005 database.  It's really a simple process, and during the import process, there's a little tick-box that allows me to "Save as SSIS package".  Which, of course, I did.

But this is the really crazy part... now that I've saved it - **where is it?**  There is no documentation I can find that tells me where this supposed SSIS package can be found, so I can run it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to SQL Server, connect to Integration Services, not Database Engine.  You should be able to find your packages within the structure that appears.

Comment: Thank you!  You'd think that would be documented somewhere...!

Answer (score 0):

You have two targets to save too:

1. SQL Server (stored in MSDB)
2. File System (you get to choose folder etc)

What did you choose?